# Is one forbidden to fast between Yom Kippur and Sukot?

Tags: yom-kippur, fast-days, sukkot, tishrei

I heard once that one shouldn’t fast between Yom Kippur and the end of Sukot , not sure its reason or if it’s an accurate statement

Answer (score 1):

One is allowed to fast at least on the day after Yom Kippur. See [O.C. 524](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=170) that mentions a custom of some people who fast 2 consecutive days of Yom Kippur, outside of Israel because of *safek hayom* (uncertainty of which day is really Yom Kippur - similar to the idea applicable to other Torah holidays.) This is a custom, and it's not a common one. (I personally, know no one that does this.)

So, at least the 11th of Tishrei is permissible for fasting. I'm unaware that there are any other restrictions to fasting on any of the other days between YK and the start of Succot. Yom Tov, itself, I think has fast restrictions; I'm not sure about Hol Hamo'ed.

Comment: I know one person who does it

Comment: @DoubleAA Very devoted person, I guess. If he would include today, he would have tied the Shushanites' record.

Comment: @danf But we really do know the dates don't we? It's just a minhag on Yom Tov for reasons I forget. Why would they have it for a fast as well?

Comment: @Orion Yes, we do know the dates now. Despite that, we still keep our father's customs as they had practiced prior to the establishment of the fixed calendar. Thus, in keeping with the practice of having 2 days Yom Tov for all other holidays, we should be fasting 2 days Yom Kippur as well. However, due to *sakanah* (danger), this 2 day practice was not generally accepted for Yom Kippur. See commentary on O.C. mentioned above where one questions even those that are, nonetheless fasting 2 days.